# props works incorrectly with componentDidUpdate.(Cash pollution)

Tags: reactjs

I have one prop that needed to update `<Select>` values each time this prop changes. Values are coming from API and they updating OK when prop changes but then, I see continuously logging this service in  "Network" section because `componentDidUpdate()` updates! Which unfortunately, causes pollution.

**sending props:**

```js
<ReportTransactionsAdmin company={companySelect} />
```

**receiving props:**

```js
getPoints = () => {
  let company = this.props.company.value;
  Axios.get("/api/point", { params: { company } })
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(res => {
      const points = res.map(point => {
        return {
          label: point.name,
          value: point.id
        };
      });

      this.setState({ points });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

**componentDidUpdate()**

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getPoints();
  }
```

**inside render():**

```js
  <div className="col-md-3 point-block">
   <label htmlFor="">Sales point</label>
   <Select
      value={point}
      isDisabled={companyIsNull ? true : false}
      name="point"
      onChange={this.pointsChange}
      noOptionsMessage={() => "Find your point from different list"}
      options={points}
      placeholder="Select point..."
   />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are calling from `getPoints` is updating state, which in turn calls `componentDidUpdate` and which call `getPoints` and so on.

`componentDidUpdate` receives a parameter `prevProps` which can be used to check if the `props` has changed from the previous update.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // you would need to safeguard the condition where company does not exist.
  if(prevProps.company.value !== this.props.company.value) {
    this.getPoints();
  }
}
```

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

---

Comment: Thank you @Boy With Silver Wings, it works. Probably I need to understand better how those lifecycles works. Btw, probably, I found other solution:   `// UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  //   this.getPoints(newProps);
  // }` ,     but prefer to use yours. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this, you can either go using PureComponent which automatically takes care of the situation you got stuck.

Also, you can implement shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle method to decide whether to invoke render() or not.

Hope this helps too..!

Comment: Thanks, seems I will need that knowledge in my future 'get stucks'. I Heard about PureComponent, but shouldComponentUpdate() is new for me.

Comment: You can read more about shouldComponentUpdate() here https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html

In case it resolves your issue, please mark the answer as accepted so that it should help others. Thanks :)